# How to get only Non NULL values as out put in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table

```
seq_id | value| data 
-------------------------
 1     | 10   | true
 1     | 11   | false
 1     | 12   | true
 2     | 13   | false
 2     | 14   | 
 2     | 15   | true
```

I wanted the resulted output with `seq_id` with those values where the data are true

```
select rs.seq_id , array_to_string(array_agg (CASE when rs.data='TRUE' then rs.value else NULL END), ', ')  as demo
    from my_table.record_set  rs 
    group by seq_id order by seq_id
```

The above query resulted all values including NULL 
How to get only Non NULL values as out put?

Answer (score 1):

Put this after "from":

```
WHERE rs.data IS NOT NULL
```

Edit: You use the "where" clause to pick the rows you want. In general "where" clauses are put after the "from" clause. If you want to only get the rows where "data" is true then you could put :

```
where rs.data = TRUE
```

Since they are booleans it is even enough with just:

```
where rs.data
```